# Build () Error with GTK# and Monodevelop on Arch

Tags: c#, linux, mono, monodevelop, gtk#

I'm trying to create a GUI for an app I created, but each time I create a New GTK# 2.0 project and press F5 get this:

```
Error CS0103: The Name 'Build' does not exist in the current subject.
```

It makes no difference if I drop a Vbox on the window or leave it as new, the error keeps appearing and nothing changes in the MainWindow.cs file.

Comment: Can you give use some details? Like which version of Xamarin Studio, which .Net runtime? By the way, when building Gtk# project, each Gtk component you add generates two files with the same name. In your case, `MainWindow.cs`. The first is visible in your solution, the second one is hidden (and auto-generated) and can be found under `gtk-gui`. Hitting F12 on the class name usually shows them both. The `Build` is declared inside that second file. Can you find such a file?

Comment: Hi Kristof and thanks for taking the time to answer, unfortunately I had a big problem with my computer and was unable to answer until know. It seems that the problem was related to the monodevelop version 'cause I updated it and then created an empty project and voilà! it works.

Comment: Thanks for the update!